# Ceiling Fan/light and 2 Switches

Tags: ceiling-fan

I have a switch with 14/2 wire that is split to two fans with lights. I also have another switch with 14/2 wire that goes to one light, no fan. I want to take out the single light fixture and connect the 14/2 wire from it to both of the lights on the ceiling fans so I can control the fan with one switch and the lights with the other. Do I just run 14/2 wire from the already existing light wiring to both fan lights?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of all the boxes involved please?

Answer (score 0):

That would work, but it depends on the fan/light combo fixture... does it have separate feeds for each function?  I.e. one pair of white & black wires for the light, and another pair for the fan?  If so, then yes.

You would have to remove the light pair from the feed coming from the switch that currently controls the fans/light combo.  Then, they can be tied to the new run of 14/2 coming from the switch you want controlling the lights.  You would have to extend that leg to the other fan (i.e. another 14/2 run going from one fan to the other), and do the same thing to that fan/light combo.

So, it depends on what the wiring inside the fan/light fixture looks like.  I would guess that it has one pair of wires for each function.

Be sure that power is off at the breaker box for BOTH light switches.  They may not necessarily be on the same circuit breaker.

Be sure everything is grounded properly.

If you're not comfortable doing electrical work, or if you don't understand the explanation above, I recommend getting help from a pro or at least someone who does understand it.

Comment: And, as ThreePhaseEel says, show some pictures!